# Java - issue with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

Ok, I've only been learning java for around a week and decided I wanted to make a text based game.
Everything was running smoothly until I started using threads.
I want to be able to detect if the user enters 'inv' at any part of the game to check their inventory.
The only problem is when I start the game, the console asks 'Do you want to play the game?' and you have to enter 'yes' twice. I think this is because the thread has an if statement that checks if it's equal to 'inv' and then checks if the user inputs 'yes' to start the game.

## (I know its probably very inefficient code, its my first game xD)

---

### The Main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game extends gameClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new gameClass());
        t1.start();

        Menu.menu();
        gameClass.beginning();

    }
}
```

### The Menu Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu{

    public static void menu() throws InterruptedException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//keyboard input

        boolean playingGame=false;
        String yesno;

        System.out.println("Welcome! Would you like to play?");

        while(playingGame==false){//repeats if until user input yes/no.
            yesno = input.nextLine();

        if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){

            playingGame = true;
            System.out.println("Great!");
```

---

### And here is the thread from the 'gameClass'

```
public void run(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{
        while(true){
            if (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("inv")){
                System.out.println(inventory);

            }else if ((input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("help"))||(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("what do i do"))){
                help();

            }
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

public static void help(){

}
}
```

---

Note : I didn't paste all of the code.

---

So when the console asks 'Welcome! Would you like to play?' I have to first enter 'yes' because the thread is checking if the next input is 'inv' Then I can move on to entering 'yes' to tell the program I want to play.

### Any help would be appreciated, this has been driving me nuts.

If you need more info just ask me :)

Comment: Why are you using threads on a console game? It is counter intuitive.

Comment: As you have discovered, unless you introduce some form of synchronisation, multiple threads don't wait for each other. The real solution is to not use thread here. If you want to use threads, it woild be easier to only have one thread interacting with the user and other threads doing the rest of the job, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one loop in your game. You read the input (once), check if it is inv or whatever, and if it's not, then you run the regular code. I see absolutely no reason for having a thread there. In fact, it makes sense you have to type yes twice: since you are hearing twice from the same input, maybe the first time the thread that checks if it is equal to inv hears it, and does nothing, and in the second time the correct thread does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you do threading, you should have all your console I/O happen from a single thread. You've got two instances of Scanner running asynchronously with each other. Even if you resolved the specific issue of asking to start the game, you could still have situations where you don't know which thread will grab your input first. In general, different threads shouldn't try to use the same resource.